# angularjs and expressjs route crash (Aw, Snap!)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I create routing in angularjs and expressjs and create `app.all('/*'...)` to make it can rander index.html, but every time I use `/*` the page will gona crash (Aw, Snap!)

**angularjs**

```
home.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider,$httpProvider)
{

   $routeProvider.when('/home',
   {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',

   })
   .when('/access_level',
   {
        templateUrl: 'access_level.html',

   })
   .when('/Users',
   {
        templateUrl: 'Users.html',

   })
   .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
   });
   $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true,requireBase: false,rewriteLinks: true});
});
```

expressjs

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
   res.sendFile('/views/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
app.get('/:name',function(req,res){
   var name = req.params.name;
   res.render(name);
});
```

so what's the matter with my code?

Comment: did you have an angular or  express error ?

Comment: @AlainIb no, I don't Have any error in angularjs and express

Comment: @AlainIb I didn't see any error in console or log

Comment: sorry i can't really help you on this. i use this syntax : `router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'index.html'));
});` without the * . take a look at this tuto maybe, 
`http://briantford.com/blog/angular-express`  or `https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finaly I found another solution, even I didn't use html5 mode in angularjs, but it's work

so, I only make views folder work's like public folder

change from

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

to

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
```

and then I only create `/` server side route (I didn't need `/:name` anymore)

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/views/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```